# Find index k at which the number of opening and closing brackets is the same

Tags: string, algorithm, performance

I was given this problem and couldn't solve it. 
The task is to find a suitable index in a string of opening/closing brackets at which the number of opening brackets in the first k chars = num of closing brackets in the remaining N-k chars.
Ex.

> "(()))))(" k would be 5 because the first 5 chars "(()))" have 2
>   opening brackets, and the remaining "))(" have 2 closing brackets.

Another example:

> "()))()" k would be 4.

k is unique. The solution should be O(N).

Comment: I think by intuition , k= number of closing brackets.
:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the preprocessing phase you can count all closing brackets in the string (let's call it `c`). Then you process every character starting from the left. Let's denote by `seenOpening` the number of processed opening brackets and by `unseenClosing` the number of closing brackets you have not yet processed. Initially `seenOpening = 0` and `unseenClosing = c`. After processing each character you increment `seenOpening` or decrement `unseenClosing` depending on the type of bracket. Whenever `seenOpening == unseenClosing` you terminate and return the index of the last character you have processed.

Answer (score 4):

Use two indexes pointing to the first and last character respectively.

While the two indexes have not crossed each other, move them as follows:

- If the character at the left index is not "(", increment it;
- if the character at the right index is not ")", decrement it;
- if neither of the above is true, then increment the left index and decrement the right index at the same time

Return the left index.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript which runs the algorithm for the two examples you have given:

```js
function partition(s) {
    var i = 0;
    var j = s.length - 1;
    while (i <= j) {
        if (s[i] !== '(') {
            i++;
        } else if (s[j] !== ')') {
            j--;
        } else {
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

console.log(partition("(()))))("));
console.log(partition("()))()"));
```

As the indexes get closer to each other in each iteration of the loop, there are at most *n* iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Java solution:

```
public int getIndexOnMatchingBracketCount(String str) { 
    int closingBracket = 0;
    int openingBracket = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == ')') {
            closingBracket++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (openingBracket == closingBracket) {
            return i;
        }

        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == ')') {
            closingBracket--;
        } else if (c == '(') {
            openingBracket++;
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are allowed to use `O(n)` space, we can do it with very easily in `O(n)` with minimal logic (as shown below in `python`):

```
def find_index(str):

    n = len(str) 
    # O(n) space: no. of '(' in first k+1 and no. of ')' in last n-k characters
    opening_in_first_k, closing_in_last_n_k = [0]*n, [0]*n 

    for i in range(1, n): # O(n) time
        opening_in_first_k[i], closing_in_last_n_k[n-1-i] = opening_in_first_k[i-1] + (str[i] == '('), \
                                                            closing_in_last_n_k[n-i] + (str[n-1-i] == ')')
    for i in range(n): # O(n) time
        if opening_in_first_k[i] == closing_in_last_n_k[i+1]:
            return i

    return -1

print find_index("(()))))(")
# 5
print find_index("()))())")
# 4
```

Comment: or, even simpler: `return str.count(')')`